# Twilio Studio Chatbot - connecting 2 callers

Tags: twilio, chatbot, twilio-studio

I have a typical chatbot setup in a Flow and one of the replies is to talk to a real estate agent. When they reply with AGENT I'm asking them "is it ok to call you now?"

If the reply is YES then I would want the flow to call the user of the chatbot using the 'Make Outgoing Call' widget?

I would think my next step is a 'Say/Play' widget when the answer that call to inform the user to hold while the agent is connected?

Then use a 'Connect Call To' widget to call the agent?

When I build this in my flow I'm not getting a call to the chatbot user.

Answer (score 1):

The use-case is very similar to the example provided by twilio for chatbot to human handoff https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/tutorials/how-to-build-a-chatbot#human-handoff

1. ask to call (send and wait for reply)
2. split on call (split based on..) Y/yes
3. make outgoing call - dial {{contact.channel.address}} - answered
4. say/play - we are connecting - audio complete
5. connect call to - in your case its the agent.

are you using dial {{contact.channel.address}} for the make outgoing call?